# how to count multiples of numbers in an input file?

Tags: c

i was trying to count the number of multiples of 2, 3, and 6 respectielly from the users input file. but for some reason, my counter is not working. can any bosy hep me please.
my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
  int num[12];
  int i;
  int counttwo;
  int countthree;
  int countsix;
  int total=0;
  printf("enter 12 integer numbers:\n");
  for(i=0;i<12;i++){

 scanf("%d", &num[i]);
  }
  for(i=0;i<12;i++){
    counttwo=0;
      if(num[i]%2==0){
       counttwo++;
      }
      countthree=0;
       if(num[i]%3==0)
  {
      countthree++;
   }
       countsix=0;
      if(num[i]%6==0)
        {
          countsix++;
}
      printf("There are %d multiples of 2:\n", counttwo);
      printf("There are %d multiples of 3:\n", countthree);
      printf("There are %d multiples of 6:\n", countsix);
}
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: **8** questions and **no** accepted answers? Passing this by.

Comment: I presume this needs a `homework` tag. And you need to learn the value of proper indentation.

Comment: Can you go to your previous questions and accept the answers to ones that answer the question you posed ? We work here for points !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reset the counter variables each iteration step. Put the

```
counttwo=0;
countthree=0;
countsix=0;
```

code before the `for()`.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what happens to the values of `counttwo`, `countthree` and `countsix` within the second loop. Pay particular attention to the lines `counttwo = 0`, `countthree = 0`, and `countsix = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

- Reset `counttwo`, `countthree`, and `countsix` to 0 before `for-loop`
- Remove redundant `for-loop` for `scanf`
- Move 3 `printf`'s out of the `for-loop`

**This is the fixed code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
  int num[12];
  int i;
  int counttwo = 0; //Reset counttwo, countthree, and countsix to 0
  int countthree = 0;
  int countsix = 0;
  int total=0;
  printf("enter 12 integer numbers:\n");

  for(i=0;i<12;i++){

      scanf("%d", &num[i]);

      if(num[i]%2==0){
       counttwo++;
      }

      if(num[i]%3==0){
       countthree++;
      }

      if(num[i]%6==0) {
        countsix++;
      }
  }

  printf("There are %d multiples of 2:\n", counttwo);
  printf("There are %d multiples of 3:\n", countthree);
  printf("There are %d multiples of 6:\n", countsix);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: perfect! thank you so much minor mistake took me almost a week to figure out. thanks again!

Comment: i was able to get the number of multiples, but i was also trying to print out the multiple numbers of 2 by adding a code at the end:


for (j=0;j<counttwo;j++)
        {

          printf("the mutipes of two are: %2d\n", num[counttwo]);
        }

it gives me an erro when i compile it.